# How to have static internal IP address for GKE nodes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, static-ip-address, gke-networking, private-cluster

I have a GKE private cluster with a Linux node pool of 2 nodes. The internal IP addresses of the nodes changes everytime it is recreated due to auto-repar/auto-upgrade. I have an external monitoring system for the nodes to check the uptime which polls the IP addresses of the nodes and most of the time it fails because of the IP address changes.

I would like to have the auto-repair mode enabled to have healthy nodes, so I won't be able to avoid the restarts.

Is it possible to have static internal IP addresses for the nodes every time they are recreated?

Comment: It does make no sense! Kubernetes is already a monitoring system that kills and spawns a new node if the previous one is unresponsive. It's for that you use Kubernetes. Else, you can simply use a manage instance group and yes you will be able to keep the same machine IP, even in case of repair/respawn.

Comment: Different use cases might have different requirements. So I wouldn't say it doesn't make no sense to have this requirement. Am aware of user-managed nodes though, am just checking the possibility for GKE managed cluster.

Comment: What's the requirements for having something outside GKE monitor the nodes? That's what autorepair does for you!

One option you can use is to have that thing that monitors the node talk to the API Server and get the IP address of the nodes on a regular basis before running the checks.

otherwise there really no option to have static internal IP addresses. GKE has built-in IPAM that handles IP assignments for nodes

Comment: @boredabdel It was an in-house monitoring system that has the details of all our applications in one place. I have the GKE monitoring in place for the same reason you stated. Just wanted to make sure before I go around to do the workaround. Thanks for the comment!